# How do I save answer choices to an access database c#

Tags: c#

I am new to programing, so this might be a simple one.
I created an access table with column "AChoices". On my Windows form, I have radio buttons A to D , which represents Answer options. When I click "Save", I would like these four answer options saved to my table. How do I save "answerA.Text,AnswerB.Text, AnswerC.Text and AnswerD.Text" in the "AChoices" column?

"INSERT into tblQuestions (QText, AChoices) Values('"txtQuestion.Text"','"Need Help Here"');

Comment: You may want to rethink your schema, as you really shouldn't try combining four values into a single column. Maybe consider either one column per value to save, or maybe one row per answer (with an extra column representing the answer number).

Comment: Thanks David. Let me try that. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simple and cheap solution but if your answers are just one word or don't use a comma, you can seperate them with a comma maybe? Add all of the four answers by seperating them with a comma. Or maybe a dollar sign.

Comment: Storing multiple values in a single column is an anti-pattern and introduces immediate need for parsing and string concatenation. Also makes it difficult to search for a given answer, since you now have to scan / search through an entire string. And what happens if your separation character conflicts with a valid character for an answer? What if you read in (or write out) data from/to a csv? Columns are cheap - there's no need to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I am very aware of this. I wouldn't use such a pattern in my applications but OP sounded like OP is trying to find a simple and quick solution, that's why I speficied in my answer that this is a cheap solution. I would use different four answer columns for each answers. If I sounded like I'm offering this simple solution as a endustrial standart solution, I want to make it clear that I'm not.